# Put the correct image in the box according to the ID

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function that loads certain image data from the database. This data is later loaded into html through * ngFor.

In order to load the image referring to this data I need to get the ID of the function that carries the image information, and then perform the function to get image with that same ID.

I can get the ID and receive all the images, however at the time of preview all the different images are loaded into the boxes but they all have the same image. (If it has 10 images, it will show the 10 to load and will stop at the last) Only the last one is visible in all boxes.

The goal is in each box to fill the image with its ID.

Can anyone help me solve?

**My HTML**

```
<div class="row tab-pane Galeria">
            <div *ngFor="let product of products" class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
              <div class="image-item" (click)="fillModal($event, product)">
                  <a class="d-block image-block h-100">
                  <homeImage> 
                        <img *ngIf="Images && Images[product.id] && inView" [src]="Images" class="Images img-fluid" alt="">                  
                  </homeImage> 
                  </a>           
                <div class="ImageText">{{product.name}}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
  GetProducts() {
    let self = this;
    this.Global.refreshToken()
      .subscribe(function (result) {
        self.homeService.getProducts()
          .then(function (resultado) {
            if (resultado) {
              self.products = resultado;
            }
          })
          .then(() => {
            if (self.products) {
              return Promise.all(self.products.map((product) => self.ImageInfo(product.id)));
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => console.error(err));
      });
  }

  ImageInfo(id) {
    var self = this;
    this.Global.refreshToken().subscribe(function (result) {
      self.homeService.getImage(id).then(function (resultado) {
        if (resultado) {
          self.Images=resultado;
        }
      }).catch();
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you share sample data what you got on product?

Comment: In products I get information like name, ID, type

Comment: Need full format json. Just post sample values.

Comment: I will add one answer here Let me know its help you or not I will remove if not working and update you.

Comment: I already added the product and image

Comment: Can you extend the one product response or add only one response json here

Comment: Please let me know which format and show full response of code

Comment: @Mokkasoru 
Already added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202397/discussion-between-mokka-soru-and-john).

Comment: got it your image

Comment: you should your image path in **product.image="src/image/image.jpg"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously your last image will display as "Images: any " has been assigned values in each iteration of products. So the last product image will be the value of Images after iteration will get completed.

Image and product id as map

```
 imagMap: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>(); 

 and use them in [src]="imagMap.get(product.id)"
```

and in the service of image :-

```
 ImageInfo(id) {
var self = this;
this.Global.refreshToken().subscribe(function (result) {
  self.homeService.getImage(id).then(function (resultado) {
    if (resultado) {
      self.Images=resultado;
      self.imagMap.set(id,resultado);
    }
  }).catch();
});
```

}

and this way it will keep track of every individual image being stored

Comment: In  'self.imagMap.put(id,resultado);' I get this error: Property 'put' does not exist on type 'Map<string, string>'

Comment: self.imagMap.set(id,resultado); use set here

Comment: I get no errors, it goes to service but does not bring the image :( the images are not showing

Comment: I evaluated what I later received in html and src appears src = null.

Must be near solution

Comment: [src]="imagMap[product.id]"  replace it with this [src]="imagMap.get(product.id)" and it will work definitely as imagMap is map not an array updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this following html. Make sure image[product.id] is available in your data.

```
<div class="row tab-pane Galeria">
        <div *ngFor="let product of products" class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <div class="image-item" (click)="fillModal($event, product)">
              <a class="d-block image-block h-100">
              <homeImage> 
                    <img *ngIf="product.images && product.images[product.id] && inView" **src=getImageUrl(product.id)** class="Images img-fluid" alt="">                  
              </homeImage> 
              </a>           
            <div class="ImageText">{{product.name}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
 getImageUrl(id){
  this.homeservice.getimageurl(id).......... // do you exact need
 }
```

Comment: I get this :  Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{product.imgpathfieldValue}}]

Comment: you have to use this only **{{}}**

Comment: I did not understand. I used this, gave no error but the images do not appear [src] = [product.imgpathfieldValue]

Comment: **imgpathfieldValue** means where your images available don't pass this exactly to src.

Comment: I get this :    Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with * ("mage> 
                        <img *ngIf="product.images && product.images[product.id] && inView" [ERROR ->]**src=getImageUrl(product.id)** >                  
Parser Error: Unexpected token * at column 25 in [getImageUrl(product.id)**] in ng:///AppModule/HomeComponent.html@9:92 ("mage> 
                        <img *ngIf="product.images && product.images[product.id] && inView" [ERROR ->]**src=getImageUrl(product.id)** class="Images img-fluid" alt="">

Answer (score 0):

Should `[src]="Images"` become `[src]="Images[product.id]"` ?

What is the structure of `Images`?

Comment: I've tested this, but get the error: Cannot read property '2009' of undefined ... 2009 is the product ID same as the image ID

Comment: can you try this?
`<homeImage *ngIf="Images[product.id] && inView> 
                        <img [src]="Images[product.id]" class="Images img-fluid" alt="">                  
                  </homeImage> `

Comment: Please let know what exactly you got error and share sample response / extend the response with image